# ClassNotFoundException when using the Mule Amazon SQS connector

Tags: mule, amazon-sqs

I'm using the Amazon SQS connector in my Mule project. When I updated it from the 2.5.5 to the 3.0.0 version according to the [user guide](http://mulesoft.github.io/sqs-connector/3.0.0/guide/install.html) and set the DEBUG logging level for the com.amazonaws package I noticed the following error right after project starts:

```
DEBUG 2015-07-20 15:15:56,927 [Receiving Thread] com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.jmx.spi.SdkMBeanRegistry: Failed to load the JMX implementation module - JMX is disabled
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:134)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.jmx.spi.SdkMBeanRegistry$Factory.<clinit>(SdkMBeanRegistry.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:351)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:316)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.AmazonWebServiceClient.requestMetricCollector(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:629)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.AmazonWebServiceClient.isRMCEnabledAtClientOrSdkLevel(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:570)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.AmazonWebServiceClient.isRequestMetricsEnabled(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:562)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.AmazonWebServiceClient.createExecutionContext(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:523)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.listQueues(AmazonSQSClient.java:1163)
    at com.amazonaws.1.9.39.shade.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.listQueues(AmazonSQSClient.java:1501)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connection.strategy.SQSConnectionManagement.connect(SQSConnectionManagement.java:173)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectionManagementSQSConnectorAdapter.connect(SQSConnectionManagementSQSConnectorAdapter.java:21)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectionManagementSQSConnectorAdapter.connect(SQSConnectionManagementSQSConnectorAdapter.java:9)
    at org.mule.devkit.3.6.1.shade.connection.management.ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.makeObject(ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.java:47)
    at org.mule.devkit.3.6.1.shade.connection.management.ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.makeObject(ConnectionManagementConnectorFactory.java:15)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.acquireConnection(SQSConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:407)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.connectivity.SQSConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.acquireConnection(SQSConnectorConfigConnectionManagementConnectionManager.java:55)
    at org.mule.devkit.3.6.1.shade.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.mule.devkit.3.6.1.shade.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessInterceptor.java:19)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.process.RetryProcessInterceptor.execute(RetryProcessInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.mule.devkit.3.6.1.shade.connection.management.ConnectionManagementProcessTemplate.execute(ConnectionManagementProcessTemplate.java:33)
    at org.mule.modules.sqs.sources.ReceiveMessagesMessageSource.run(ReceiveMessagesMessageSource.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It's true, the mule-module-sqs-3.0.0.jar downloaded by Maven doesn't contain such class. I rebuild the Amazon SQS connector's source code with little changes in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/mulesoft/sqs-connector/blob/develop/pom.xml): set `<minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>` for the `maven-shade-plugin`. Then the missing class appeared in the jar and I managed to run the project without errors.

Not sure is it a bug or not but don't like the idea to build the connector manually. Will really appreciate if you help me to sort it out. Thanks.

Comment: This log line is at `DEBUG` level so it doesn't seem to be an actual issue.

Comment: Are you using the latest Studio? and what mule version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the 3.5 CE Mule and the latest Studio. Yes, this can be seen only at the Debug level.

Comment: Okay, I talked to the connector developers, they told that this is a minor bug which has already been fixed in the upcoming 3.1.0 release. And yes, It can be ignored for now as it's seen only on the debug mode.